# How to access list of arbitrary depth?

Tags: python, list

I have a list known as `data` which can be any depth equal to or greater than `1`.

**e.g;**

Sometimes `data = [3,65,3]`

or `data = [[3,65,3],[88,44,9],[6,2,21]]` ... and so on.

How would I generally access `data`, considering it's depth can fluctuate? It's assumed that the depth and indexes to access an element (a number) will always be known.

**I.e.**

Say I have a function `f` that takes arbitrary arguments. How would I generalize the following?

```
f(a , b, c...)
    if depth = 1:
        return data[a]
    elif depth = 2:
        return data[a][b]
    elif depth = 3:
        return data[a][b][c]
    ...
    and so on
```

Comment: Lists don't really have dimensions. Can you give an example of the input? I.e. you say the "dimension and indexes" will always be known, so, what exactly would you be working with?

Comment: Sounds like you want to flatten a list of arbitrary depth.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, I suppose that would work

Comment: What would be your output? How does a, b, c and depth come into this?

Comment: @JonClements A number, at the lowest depth of the list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes that would solve the problem of arbitrary arguments, however does not solve generalizing `[a]`, `[a][b]`, `[a][b][b]`...

Comment: Just loop over the indices. There is a duplicate out there, and I'm trying to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iteratively access sublists based on the number of indices you provide, which implicitly means that's the depth. You can further make checks for the legality of the arguments if you don't trust the user to always provide valid indices.

```
def f(*indices):
    element = data
    for index in indices:
        element = element[index]
    return element
```

You can also edit the value at some index, which will be done in place.

```
def f(indices, value):
    if not len(indices):
        return
    element = data
    for index in indices[:-1]:
        element = element[index]
    element[indices[-1]] = value
```

`indices` is supposed to be a loop, so you'd be expected to call it as `f((1, 1), 5)`. If instead you would prefer to call it as `f(1, 1, 5)`, where all the arguments are the indices and the ast one is the new value, then change the function to

```
def f(*args):
    indices, value = args[:-1], args[-1]
    # then the same as above
```

Comment: Aha I should have thought of that earlier. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Using this approach, would it be also possible to alter the element at the specific indices too?

Comment: @Graviton Yes, it can be done. I have updated the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input would be like this:

```
data = [[3,65,3],[88,44,[9, 4, 56]],[6,2,21]]
```

you can flatten it like this:

```
def flatten(l):
     r = []
     for e in l:
         if isinstance(e, list):
            r += flatten(e)
         else:
            r.append(e)
     return r
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> flatten([[3,65,3],[88,44,[9, 4, 56]],[6,2,21]])
[3, 65, 3, 88, 44, 9, 4, 56, 6, 2, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive solution using generators:

```
def flatten(s):
  if not isinstance(s, list):
      yield s
  else:
      for i in s:
          for b in flatten(i):
              yield b

print(list(flatten([[3,65,[3, [[5, 6, [2, 6, [4]]]]],[88,44,[9, 4, 56]],[6,2,21]]])))
```

Output:

```
[3, 65, 3, 5, 6, 2, 6, 4, 88, 44, 9, 4, 56, 6, 2, 21]
```